# React Redux "A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch" Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to change state using dispatch().
So I used the (...) operator to copy the object and change the state like this: By the way, an error occurs when the event is "user-changed-channel".
No cause found. Please help.

```
    export default function channels(state = initialState, action) {
      // console.log(action);
      switch (action.type) {
        case SETCHANNELS: {
          if (action.event === "user-changed-channel") {
            // return { ...state, channels: {} };
          }

          const {
            event,
            socketId,
            sender,
            originChannel,
            new_channels,
            changed_channel,
          } = action;
          const obj = updateChannels({
            new_channels,
            event,
            socketId,
            sender,
            originChannel,
            changed_channel,
            state,
          });
          return { ...state, channels: obj };
        }
        default:
          return { ...state };
      }
    }
```

```
    //updateChannels function


        export function updateChannels({
         event,
         new_channels,
         originChannel,
         state,
         changed_channel,
     sender,
    }) {
     if (event === "init") {
       return new_channels;
     }
    
     if (event === "user-changed-channel") {
      const obj = { ...state.channels };
       if (originChannel !== null && originChannel !== undefined) {
        const members = { ...obj[originChannel]["members"] };
         delete members[sender.socketId];
         obj[originChannel]["members"] = members;
       }
       obj[changed_channel].members[sender.socketId] = sender;
       return obj;
      }
    }
```

I thought I would use the (...) operator and the object would be copied, keeping the state immutable, and then modified.However, I get the above error message only from "user-changed-channel".
I checked all the values ​​I send to dispatch() and they all come out fine too. Values ​​returned from the updateChannels function are also often passed. However, the problem only occurs when saving to state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const obj = { ...state.channels }` only shallow copies the references into a new object reference, e.g. `obj` is a new object but all the properties still point into the `state.channels`'s properties. Both `obj[originChannel]["members"] = members;` and `obj[changed_channel].members[sender.socketId] = sender;` are the mutations of the `obj[changed_channel]` object reference.

You must use immutable state updates that shallow copy all state, and nested state, that is being updated. This means `obj[changed_channel]` and any additional nested properties also need to be shallow copied.

Basic example:

```js
if (event === "user-changed-channel") {
  const obj = {                          // <-- new reference
    ...state.channels,                   // <-- shallow copy
    [originChannel]: {                   // <-- new reference
      ...state[originChannel],           // <-- shallow copy
      members: {                         // <-- new reference
        ...state[originChannel].members, // <-- shallow copy
        [sender.socketId]: sender
      },
    }
  };

  if (originChannel !== null && originChannel !== undefined) {
    delete obj[originChannel].members[sender.socketId]; // <-- safe mutation of new reference
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the state here:

```js
obj[originChannel]["members"] = members
```

...and here:

```js
obj[changed_channel].members[sender.socketId] = sender;
```

You are only creating a shallow copy, not a deep copy, so even though it's true that `obj !== state.channels` we do still have `obj.something === state.channels.something`.